# #1054 - Unknown column 't2.id_pro' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name as tipo, t1.id as id_tracker,
    t2.name as nombre_pro, t2.id as id_pro, 
    t3.project_id as pro_tra_id, t3.tracker_id as id_pro_tra_id2 
FROM trackers t1, projects t2, projects_trackers t3 
WHERE t2.id_pro=t3.pro_tra_id and 
    t1.id_tracker=t3.id_pro_tra_id2 and
    t3.pro_tra_id=1
```

But the same throws me the following error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 't2.id_pro' in 'where clause'

I don't really understand that it can happen if someone could help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: please send error output

Comment: reformat the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
t1.name as tipo, t1.id as id_tracker,
t2.name as nombre_pro, t2.id as id_pro, 
t3.project_id as pro_tra_id, t3.tracker_id as id_pro_tra_id2 
FROM 
trackers t1, projects t2, projects_trackers t3 
WHERE t2.id = t3.project_id 
AND t1.id = t3.tracker_id 
AND t3.project_id=1
```

If you use `SELECT t1.name as tipo` you can either use `tipo` or `t1.name` but *not* `t1.tipo`. Also, I don't believe you can use the aliases in the WHERE clause.